# VBA text to columns isnt working on every row of a text file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module in ThisWorkbook that is supposed to open .txt files from a location (it does so in another workbook), then do text to columns, then copy the individual columns and paste into ThisWorkbook. The .txt files have data in the format 23,100,100.65 on each row: three numbers separated by commas.

Something strange is happening though, as the text to columns function works on data in some cells, but not others. Furthermore, it seems that when the .txt file opens in a workbook, some of the commas separating the data are in the wrong place, or an extra comma has been added. The picture below shows the text file on the left and the commensurate Excel and resultant data on the right. Row 300,000 is a good example of the weird problem.

[image: Text file on left, Excel workbook on right]

Here's my code, is there anything in the way i've written it that is leading to these problems? If not, any ideas whats going on?

```
Sub OpenTxtFiles()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim xFolder As String
Dim txtFname As String
Dim cellAddr As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rngTtC As Range

xFolder = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
Set rng = Range("E1:I1") 'the range contains the text filenames

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


            For Each cell In rng
                txtFname = cell.Value   'sets the cell value as txtFname variable
                    'MsgBox txtFname
                cellAddr = cell.Address    'sets the cell address as cellAddr variable
                    'MsgBox cellAddr
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=xFolder & "\" & txtFname    'opens the text file relating to the cell value
                        Set rngTtC = ActiveSheet.[A:A]    'this bit does text to columns on the csv for ease of copying the columns in next bit
                        rngTtC.TextToColumns Destination:=rngTtC, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                        textqualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, consecutivedelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                        semicolon:=False, comma:=True, Space:=False
```

Comment: Some of those are true numbers and are not being treated as text with commas that can be split. Look in the formula bar or just widen the column to show left alignment (text) and right alignment (numbers).

Comment: Suggest you change to [workbooks.opentext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel) and skip the TextToColumns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you change to [workbooks.opentext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel) and skip the TextToColumns.

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="c:\test\numbertext.csv"
```

I thought I would have to fill in a lot of customized parameters but the defaults seem to work for the small portion I retyped from your sample data.

```
259,1198,114.2290
259,1199,114.2290
259,1200,114.2290
251,1,27.0960
251,2,27.0960
251,3,27.0960
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! thanks very much. It didnt work just with `WorkBooks.OpenText` (all data was in column A with some as numbers and some as text) so from the link you provided i added `DataType:=xlDelimited, comma:=True` after the filename and it seems to have worked perfectly, and loads quicker than using text to columns.